# Catching AggregateException

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

I am trying to throw and catch an AggregateException.
I did not use exceptions very much on C#, but the behaviour I found is a little bit surprising.

My code is:

```
var numbers = Enumerable.Range(0, 20);

try
{
    var parallelResult = numbers.AsParallel()
        .Where(i => IsEven(i));
    parallelResult.ForAll(e => Console.WriteLine(e));

}
catch (AggregateException e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("There was {0} exceptions", e.InnerExceptions.Count());
}
```

It is calling the function IsEven

```
private static bool IsEven(int i)
{
    if (i % 10 == 0)
        throw new AggregateException("i");
    return i % 2 == 0;
}
```

That throws the AggregateException.

I would expect the code to write every even number in the 0,20 range and "There was 1 exceptions" twice.

What I get is some numbers printed (they are random cause of ForAll) and then the exception is thrown, but not catched and the programs stop.

Am i missing something?

Comment: Am not sure why this happens, try changing the `throw new AggregateException("i");` to `throw new ArgumentException("i");` produces the expected result

Comment: Throwing `throw new AggregateException("i", new[] { new ArgumentException("i") });` also helps, but no idea why your version crashes the app

Comment: You are confusing the system by throwing the wrong exception. Throw an Argument or InvalidOperationException instead.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel - _why your version crashes the app_ - I have to speculate, but its InnerExceptions will be empty. Unexpected.

Comment: @HenkHolterman Did you tried? It is strange that App crashes even when we wrap the code with try/catch :( I agree with you `InnerExceptions` should have exceptions, when I do this `throw new AggregateException("i", new[] { new ArgumentException("i") })` it works perfectly

Comment: @SriramSakthivel - but inner code should not throw Aggregate. Not their job.

Comment: @HenkHolterman Of course, i know it is a bad idea and AggregateException's purpose is to combine many exceptions and preserve StackTrace. but I can't find any documentation which states we shoudn't do that

Comment: The inner exception is actually null, but even replacing the exception throw with throw new AggregateException("i", new[] { new ArgumentException("i") }); I get an error saying AggregateException was unhandled by user code

Comment: Stop throwing AggregateException

Comment: The line "parallelResult.ForAll(e => Console.WriteLine(e));"
throws a DisposedException "The query enumerator has been disposed"
...strange...

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This is actually kind of interesting. I think the problem is that you're using `AggregateException` in an unexpected way, which is causing an error inside the PLINQ code.

The entire point of `AggregateException` is to group together multiple exceptions that may occur simultaneously (or nearly so) in a parallel process. So `AggregateException` is expected to have at least one inner exception. But you're throwing `new AggregateException("i")`, which has no inner exceptions.  The PLINQ code tries to examine the `InnerExceptions` property, hits some sort of error (probably a `NullPointerException`) and then it seems to go into a loop of some sort. This is arguably a bug in PLINQ, since you're using a valid constructor for `AggregateException`, even if it is an unusual one.

As pointed out elsewhere, throwing `ArgumentException` would be more semantically correct. But you can get the behavior you're looking for by throwing a correctly-constructed `AggregateException`, for example by changing the `IsEven` function to something like this:

```
private static bool IsEven(int i)
{
    if (i % 10 == 0){
        //This is still weird
        //You shouldn't do this. Just throw the ArgumentException.
        throw new AggregateException(new ArgumentException("I hate multiples of 10"));
    }
    return i % 2 == 0;
}
```

I think the moral of the story is to not throw `AggregateException` unless you really know exactly what you're doing, particularly if you're already inside a parallel or `Task`-based operation of some kind.

Comment: Please edit so that you have the proper version of code (throwing ArgumentException instead of throwing AggregateException). You did say in the end but I am afraid people who would take a glance and think the posted code is the proper one (which is not).

Comment: Threw in a comment that you shouldn't do as I did.

Answer (score 8):

I agree with others: this is a bug in .Net and you should [report it](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/).

The cause is in the method `QueryEnd()` in the internal class `QueryTaskGroupState`.
Its decompiled (and slightly modified for clarity) code looks like this:

```
try
{
  this.m_rootTask.Wait();
}
catch (AggregateException ex)
{
  AggregateException aggregateException = ex.Flatten();
  bool cacellation = true;
  for (int i = 0; i < aggregateException.InnerExceptions.Count; ++i)
  {
    var canceledException =
        aggregateException.InnerExceptions[i] as OperationCanceledException;
    if (IsCancellation(canceledException))
    {
      cacellation = false;
      break;
    }
  }
  if (!cacellation)
    throw aggregateException;
}
finally
{
  this.m_rootTask.Dispose();
}
if (!this.m_cancellationState.MergedCancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
  return;
if (!this.m_cancellationState.TopLevelDisposedFlag.Value)
  CancellationState.ThrowWithStandardMessageIfCanceled(
    this.m_cancellationState.ExternalCancellationToken);
if (!userInitiatedDispose)
  throw new ObjectDisposedException(
    "enumerator", "The query enumerator has been disposed.");
```

Basically, what this does is:

- rethrow the flattened `AggregateException` if it contains any non-cancellation exceptions
- throw new cancellation exception if cancellation was requested (or return without throwing, I don't really understand that part, but I don't think it's relevant here)
- else throw `ObjectDisposedException` for some reason (assuming `userInitiatedDispose` is `false`, which it is)

So, if you throw an `AggregateException` with no inner exceptions, `ex` will be an `AggregateException` containing your empty `AggregateExcaption`. Calling `Flatten()` will turn that into just an empty `AggreateException`, which means it doesn't contain any non-cancellation exception, so the first part of the code thinks this is cancellation and doesn't throw.

But the second part of the code realizes this isn't cancellation, so it throws a completely bogus exception.

Comment: 8  years later the bug is still here in .Net 5

Comment: Reported: [https://github.com/dotnet/core/issues/5900](https://github.com/dotnet/core/issues/5900)

Comment: according to the link its fixed in .Net 6, just to let anyone here know