# Task.Wait unexpected behavior in case of OperationCanceledException

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library, wait, cancellation

Consider the following piece of code:

```
CancellationTokenSource cts0 = new CancellationTokenSource(), cts1 = new CancellationTokenSource();
try
{
    var task = Task.Run(() => { throw new OperationCanceledException("123", cts0.Token); }, cts1.Token);
    task.Wait();
}
catch (AggregateException ae) { Console.WriteLine(ae.InnerException); }
```

Due to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997396%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) task should be in `Faulted` state because it's token does not match exception's token (and also `IsCancellationRequested` is `false`):

> If the token's IsCancellationRequested property returns false or if the exception's token does not match the Task's token, the OperationCanceledException is treated like a normal exception, causing the Task to transition to the Faulted state.

When I launch this code in console app using .NET 4.5.2 I get task in `Canceled` state (aggregate exception contains unknown `TaskCanceledExeption`, not the original). And all information of original exception is lost (message, inner exception, custom data).

I also noticed that behavior of `Task.Wait` differs from `await task` in case of `OperationCanceledException`.

```
try { Task.Run(() => { throw new InvalidOperationException("123"); }).Wait(); } // 1
catch (AggregateException ae) { Console.WriteLine(ae.InnerException); }

try { await Task.Run(() => { throw new InvalidOperationException("123"); }); } // 2
catch (InvalidOperationException ex) { Console.WriteLine(ex); }

try { Task.Run(() => { throw new OperationCanceledException("123"); }).Wait(); } // 3 
catch (AggregateException ae) { Console.WriteLine(ae.InnerException); }

try { await Task.Run(() => { throw new OperationCanceledException("123"); }); } // 4
catch (OperationCanceledException ex) { Console.WriteLine(ex); }
```

Cases `1` and `2` produce almost identical result (differ only in `StackTrace`), but when I change exception to `OperationCanceledException`, then I get very different results: an unknown `TaskCanceledException` in case `3` without original data, and expected `OpeartionCanceledException` in case `4` with all original data (message, etc.).

So the question is: Does MSDN contain incorrect information? Or is it a bug in .NET? Or maybe it's just I don't understand something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is a bug.  `Task.Run`  under the hood calls `Task<Task>.Factory.StartNew`.  This internal Task is getting the right Status of Faulted.  The wrapping task is not.

You can work around this bug by calling

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { throw new OperationCanceledException("123", cts0.Token); }, cts1.Token, TaskCreationOptions.DenyChildAttach, TaskScheduler.Default);
```

Though, you'll lose the other feature of `Task.Run` which is unwrapping.  See:
[Task.Run vs Task.Factory.StartNew](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2011/10/24/10229468.aspx)

**More Details:**

Here's the code of `Task.Run` where you see that it is creating a wrapping `UnwrapPromise` (which derives from `Task<TResult>`:

```
public static Task Run(Func<Task> function, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    // Check arguments
    if (function == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("function");
    Contract.EndContractBlock();

    cancellationToken.ThrowIfSourceDisposed();

    // Short-circuit if we are given a pre-canceled token
    if (cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        return Task.FromCancellation(cancellationToken);

    // Kick off initial Task, which will call the user-supplied function and yield a Task.
    Task<Task> task1 = Task<Task>.Factory.StartNew(function, cancellationToken, TaskCreationOptions.DenyChildAttach, TaskScheduler.Default);

    // Create a promise-style Task to be used as a proxy for the operation
    // Set lookForOce == true so that unwrap logic can be on the lookout for OCEs thrown as faults from task1, to support in-delegate cancellation.
    UnwrapPromise<VoidTaskResult> promise = new UnwrapPromise<VoidTaskResult>(task1, lookForOce: true);

    return promise;
}
```

The Task constructor which it calls does not take a cancellation token (and thus it does not know about the inner Task's cancellation token).  Notice it creates a default CancellationToken instead.  Here's the ctor it calls:

```
internal Task(object state, TaskCreationOptions creationOptions, bool promiseStyle)
{
    Contract.Assert(promiseStyle, "Promise CTOR: promiseStyle was false");

    // Check the creationOptions. We only allow the AttachedToParent option to be specified for promise tasks.
    if ((creationOptions & ~TaskCreationOptions.AttachedToParent) != 0)
    {
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("creationOptions");
    }

    // m_parent is readonly, and so must be set in the constructor.
    // Only set a parent if AttachedToParent is specified.
    if ((creationOptions & TaskCreationOptions.AttachedToParent) != 0)
        m_parent = Task.InternalCurrent;

    TaskConstructorCore(null, state, default(CancellationToken), creationOptions, InternalTaskOptions.PromiseTask, null);
}
```

The outer task (the `UnwrapPromise` adds a continuation).  The continuation examines the inner task.   In the case of the inner task being faulted, it consideres finding a a OperationCanceledException as indicating cancellation (regardless of a matching token).  Below is the `UnwrapPromise<TResult>.TrySetFromTask` (below is also the call stack showing where it gets called).  Notice the Faulted state:

```
private bool TrySetFromTask(Task task, bool lookForOce)
{
    Contract.Requires(task != null && task.IsCompleted, "TrySetFromTask: Expected task to have completed.");

    bool result = false;
    switch (task.Status)
    {
        case TaskStatus.Canceled:
            result = TrySetCanceled(task.CancellationToken, task.GetCancellationExceptionDispatchInfo());
            break;

        case TaskStatus.Faulted:
            var edis = task.GetExceptionDispatchInfos();
            ExceptionDispatchInfo oceEdi;
            OperationCanceledException oce;
            if (lookForOce && edis.Count > 0 &&
                (oceEdi = edis[0]) != null &&
                (oce = oceEdi.SourceException as OperationCanceledException) != null)
            {
                result = TrySetCanceled(oce.CancellationToken, oceEdi);
            }
            else
            {
                result = TrySetException(edis);
            }
            break;

        case TaskStatus.RanToCompletion:
            var taskTResult = task as Task<TResult>;
            result = TrySetResult(taskTResult != null ? taskTResult.Result : default(TResult));
            break;
    }
    return result;
}
```

*Call stack:*

```
    mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.Tasks.Task<System.Threading.Tasks.VoidTaskResult>.TrySetCanceled(System.Threading.CancellationToken tokenToRecord, object cancellationException) Line 645 C#
    mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.Tasks.UnwrapPromise<System.Threading.Tasks.VoidTaskResult>.TrySetFromTask(System.Threading.Tasks.Task task, bool lookForOce) Line 6988 + 0x9f bytes   C#
    mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.Tasks.UnwrapPromise<System.Threading.Tasks.VoidTaskResult>.ProcessCompletedOuterTask(System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) Line 6956 + 0xe bytes  C#
    mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.Tasks.UnwrapPromise<System.Threading.Tasks.VoidTaskResult>.InvokeCore(System.Threading.Tasks.Task completingTask) Line 6910 + 0x7 bytes   C#
    mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.Tasks.UnwrapPromise<System.Threading.Tasks.VoidTaskResult>.Invoke(System.Threading.Tasks.Task completingTask) Line 6891 + 0x9 bytes   C#
    mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.Tasks.Task.FinishContinuations() Line 3571    C#
    mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.Tasks.Task.FinishStageThree() Line 2323 + 0x7 bytes   C#
    mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.Tasks.Task.FinishStageTwo() Line 2294 + 0x7 bytes C#
    mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Finish(bool bUserDelegateExecuted) Line 2233   C#
    mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteWithThreadLocal(ref System.Threading.Tasks.Task currentTaskSlot) Line 2785 + 0xc bytes  C#
    mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteEntry(bool bPreventDoubleExecution) Line 2728   C#
    mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.Tasks.Task.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem() Line 2664 + 0x7 bytes   C#
    mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch() Line 829   C#
    mscorlib.dll!System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallback() Line 1170 + 0x5 bytes   C#
```

It notices the OperationCanceledException and calls TrySetCanceled to put the task into the cancelled state.

**An aside:**

Another thing to note is that when you start using `async` methods, there isn't really a way to register a cancellation token with an `async` method.  Thus, *any* OperationCancelledException that gets encountered in an async methods is considered a cancellation.
See 
[Associate a CancellationToken with an async method's Task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15257356/associate-a-cancellationtoken-with-an-async-methods-taks)

Answer (score 5):

**Matt Smith** - Thank you, your explanation was very helpful.

After reading it and testing for a while I noticed that original question does not fully correct. It's not a problem of `Task.Wait`. I can get this wrong behavior with `Task.ContinueWith`, checking first task's `Status` - it is `Canceled`. So I believe the final answer is:

*If you create a task using `Task.Run` overloads that take `Func<Task>` or `Func<Task<TResult>>` as a first argument, and your delegate throws `OperationCanceledException`, and if you use `Task.Wait` or `Task.ContinueWith` on returned task, then you will lose original exception with all it's data because of bug in .NET (as **Matt Smith** explained) and get task in incorrect `Canceled` state instead of `Faulted`, regardless of matching [documented logic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997396%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).*

All of these conditions matter. If you use `await` on created task - it works fine. If you use `Task.Run` overloads that take `Action` or `Func<TResult>` as a first argument - it works fine in all cases (Wait, ContinueWith, await).

I also noticed strange behavior of overloaded method selection logic. When I write

```
Task.Run(() => { throw new OperationCanceledException("123", cts0.Token); }, cts1.Token);
```

I expect to use `Task.Run(Action, CancellationToken)` overload, which is not broken. But somehow it appears that broken `Task.Run(Func<Task>, CancellationToken)` is used. So I'm forced to do something like this

```
Task.Run((Action)(() => { throw new OperationCanceledException("123", cts0.Token); }), cts1.Token);
```

or use `TaskFactory.StartNew`.

Answer (score 4):

This behavior is very interesting and strange, at the same time.
The purpose of the [`AggregateException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.aggregateexception%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), as its name says, is to group together multiple exceptions/errors that happen during the execution of an application. So, in your 3rd case, you have an `OperationCanceledException` as inner exception and the stack trace of the `AggregateException` should report everything about that, including the data (like `123`), as it is shown below in the 4th case:

[image]

About your questions:

> Does MSDN contain incorrect information?

It should report always the correct and precise information about the behavior of classes, methods and so on.

> Or is it a bug in .NET?

Most probably, yes, it is a bug. It's not understandable why this happens. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19266338/catching-aggregateexception) you'll find a related question about this issue. Please [report](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/) this problem to Microsoft.